# Force regex to be case sensitive?

Tags: notepad++

Suddenly my notepad++ regex search became case insensitive. Which is highly problematic to me.

It's the first time I notice this, I searched the internet but the only topics I find are to turn regex case insensitive.

Is there any way to force them to be case sensitive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, check the checkbox "Match Case":

[image]

Comment: Lol ! Ok you can call me blind
Thanks

Comment: try add /i to the end of your regular expression

Comment: that worked, thank you, I wonder why I never noticed this box was influencing regex, I have been working with them for 2 years now.